# Gmail Update: Tab Filters? Where did they go?

Tags: gmail

Gmail has 4 tabs: Primary, Social, Promotions, Updates, Forums.

With the old Classic Gmail, when I would drag and drop an email from one tab to another, Gmail would ask me if I wanted all similar messages to appear in the same destination tab in the future. This was VERY convenient.

This no longer happens.

1. Is there still some way to do this?
2. Is there a way to reset all my tab filters and start again?